# Android MediaPlayer logs No content provider error but works

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I create an instance of MediaPlayer to play an mp3 file from the Internet:

```
var player = MediaPlayer()
player.setDataSource(this, uri, headers)
```

The uri variable is of type Uri and contains the address of the mp3 file on the Internet. I can open this address in a browser. The headers variable contains the Authorization field with a username and password or does not contain anything if access to the file is free.

MediaPlayer is initialized normally and plays this file when I call the start function.

But for some reason, when calling setDataSource, the following error is generated in the log:

```
2020-05-19 05:27:59.096 4070-4070/com.myname.myapp W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open https://my.url/...
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://my.url/audio/cmn-balm-hsk1/cmn-2a3f599e.mp3
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1673)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1503)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1420)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.attemptDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1101)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1073)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1097)
    at com.myname.myapp.MainActivity.updateCurrentAudioFiles(MainActivity.kt:209)
```

What is the reason of this error? How to fix it?